# Complete proof derivative with limit

Tags: calculus

I have seen many ways to proof it, but I got stuck with the limit way (the proof taking the definitions of a derivative, rather using logarithms etc. I want to see a solid proof for the exponential derivative without relying on logarithms etc.)
After I did some algebra we all know we end up with the exponential functions times the limit. Because I dont know how to format fractions etc. im unable to show you the math, but Im sure you understand what I mean. In my math book, i see $f(x) = a^x \implies f'(x) = a^x\ln(a)$, this $\ln(a)$ part is the part I'm intersted in, since the proof with limits gives the conclusion $\ln(a)$ is equal to that limit value. But how is the natural logarithm of a equal to the limit?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $\,a^x\,$ is defined as
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}{h} = a^x\frac{a^h-1}{h}$$
Now let $\,h = 1/n\,$ in
$$\frac{a^h-1}{h} = b \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a = (b\cdot h + 1)^{1/h} = \left(1 + \frac{b}{n}\right)^n$$
We  hope you know that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{b}{n}\right)^n = e^b $$
Because then we can conclude$$e^b = a \quad \Longrightarrow \quad b = \ln(a)$$

Comment: Uhmm could you elaborate more please? Some steps, like the last three, are too fast for me;p

Comment: Does the following reference help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition

Comment: And another one, showing (on top) the relationship between $\ln(x)$ and $e^x$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Logarithm